# Create an OAuth server for company Active directory using Asp.Net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I need to create a web application host outside of the company network. However, it needs to be authenticated using the company's Active Directory.

The application will have an angular site and some Asp.Net core web API services. The Angular will authenticate using the company AD and use the token to access the web API services if it's authorized.

I'm thinking of creating an Asp.Net core service inside the company for authentication. The outside components access it through the firewall and get authenticated.

Is it a valid architecture? Is there any example?

**Update:**

I plan to use IdentityServer4 for this.

1. Does it support the coming .Net core 3/Asp.Net core 3?
2. Is there any example for IdentityServer integrating the company's Active Directory?

   - I think I need to use the sample UI on the web or desktop front-end and need the backend to authenticate the login using AD, and the authorizition.

Comment: I would not authenticate with angular, but instead authenticate with Asp, then return a token to the browser. But, essentially, it is a valid architecture. Check this out: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/216/windows-authentication-with-asp-net-web-pages

Comment: You'll likely want to use IdentityServer for this. It can plug in AD as an external prodivider, somewhat akin to logging in via Google, Facebook, etc. Direct Windows Auth is impossible unless everything is on the same domain, which won't be possible here, so your users will have to actually login, i.e. enter their domain user and password.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, it's ok for the users to enter the domain user and password. I just need to authenticate AD for now. Is IdentityServer too heavy for it? Is it free to use? (So I don't need to ask for approval).

Comment: IdentityServer is free and open-source. It's supported by the .NET Foundation (though I think they do offer paid support/consultation services).